# Imported video is not interacting with the lights

Tags: image, lighting

I've brought a tiny animation into my scene as an image plane but it is not being affected by the spotlight. The animation loop plays fine.

Any assistance would be welcome.

[image]

Comment: What shading method did you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what to call this? I've just added a pic of the setup

Comment: No screenshot was added. When importing images as planes using the addon, you can set it to Principled, Shadeless, or Emit. If you did something yourself, a screenshot is a good idea.

Comment: Uh oh even adding a screenshot proves too difficult for me. I have added one now I believe.

Comment: Yes, now you have.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, to be “shadeless” means to not react to scene lighting at all. If you want the material to react to the lights, you should just plug the image color into a regular BSDF node, such as a Principled BSDF node. Replace the IAP_SHADELESS group node with a BSDF.

Comment: I should delete the IAP_SHADELESS, add a Principled BSDF node, then connect the color output from the sleeping head image to the base color of the BSDF?

Comment: @Bob Yes. The Transparent and Mix nodes are set up correctly, and can stay. Pretty much a drop-in replacement. I will note though that if you use a Principled BSDF, the mixer set-up is no longer necessary, since the Principled BSDF has its own alpha input.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your assistance.